# Horizontal form - Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

Today I copied literally a test piece of code from the [twitter-bootstrap site](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#forms) into my code. I tried to get a horizontal form like in the example. but for some reason, I don't get a horzontal layout. My site http://073design.nl/kasopmaak/?

Code i used for horizontal form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
      </label>
      <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code works fine only when link with bootstrap version 2.3 **[DEMO1](https://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/uabqcpqf/)**

**[Check this](https://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/L17m2boq/)** works in bootstrap 3

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label col-xs-2">Email</label>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label col-xs-2">Password</label>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```